# 'vtkobject' object is not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, iteration, vtk

In one class "LineLogic", I have the following code portion:

```
probe = vtk.vtkProbeFilter() 
probe.SetInputConnection(line.GetOutputPort())
probe.SetSourceData(volumeNode.GetImageData())
probe.Update()

# return VTK array
return probe.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('ImageScalars')
```

In another class, I do the following to iterate through the array:

```
logic = LineLogic()
sampleData = logic.probeVolume(volumeNode,rulerNode)
    for data in sampleData:
      if not (isinstance(data,int) or isinstance(data,float) or isinstance(data,long) or isinstance(data,complex)):
        raise ValueError('non numeric data')
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'vtkobject' object is not iterable
```

in the line:

```
for data in sampleData:
```

Why is that? Aren't we getting an array returned?

Comment: @Anand S Kumar: Don't you have anything better to do?

Comment: Instances of `vtk.vtkProbeFilter` don't seem to have a `GetOutput()` method according to this [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/6.2/html/classvtkProbeFilter.html).